# name router outlet dosent show angular component

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar and there is a section next to it which responsible for showing componentnts.
Inside of the section tag I put router-outlet this way:

```
    <router-outlet name="adminoutlet"></router-outlet>
```

and there is a link in sidebar tag :

```
<a [routerLink]="[ { outlets: { adminoutlet: ['projecttype'] } }]" style="margin-bottom: 5px"
                                   class="list-group-item list-margin"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> project kind</a>
```

and there is a routes in a file like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "admin", component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, PermissionGuard], data: { pageid: "f4e8c4ed-9871-40ab-98c1-75e9608d822a" } },
    { path: "admin/projecttype", component: ProjectTypeComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/area", component: AreaComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/iteration", component: IterationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/member", component: MemberComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/workitemtype", component: WorkItemTypeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/state", component: StateComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: "admin/memberiteration", component: MemberIterationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/memberarea", component: MemberAreaComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/workitemtypestate", component: WorkItemTypeStateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/reason", component: ReasonComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: "admin/workitemlinktype", component: WorkItemLinkTypeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/board", component: BoardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/column", component: ColumnComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/boardworkitemtype", component: BoardWorkItemTypeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/fieldvalue", component: FieldValueComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/workitemtypelink", component: WorkItemTypeLinkComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/fieldcategory", component: FieldCategoryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/field", component: FieldComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: "admin/workitemtype-field", component: WorkItemTypeFieldComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: "admin/workitemtype-fieldvalue", component: WorkItemTypeFieldValueComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/team", component: TeamComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/fieldOrder", component: WorkitemFieldOrderComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/copytemplate", component: CopytemplateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/informationNote", component: informationNoteComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/boardTag", component: BoardTagComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/configIssueReportAccess", component: ConfigIssueReportAccessComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/productResources", component: ProductResourcesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/label", component: LabelComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/editproject", component: EditProjectComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/defineFamsBotCommand", component: DefineFamsBotCommandComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "admin/importanceDegree", component: ConfigImportanceDegreeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

But once I click on that component , it dosen't show in router-outlet and it opens somewhere else standalone And I get this error below.

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
> 'team' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'team'

Answer (score 0):

Just write in your app.components.ts

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And then in your navigation component make

```
<a [routerLink]=“projecttype”>Project type</a>
```

Comment: router-outlet it in not in app.components.ts .it is in another file admin.template.ts